What does ともとれない here mean?
自分は頷くともとれないうつむきをして、これを受け取り、走り去った。
the character in this passage is given a weapon. As far I can see, he hangs his head accepts it and then leaves? I can't quite understand how 頷くともとれないis divided


頷く means "to nod" as a sign of agreement.
This とる (取る in kanji) means "to interpret/take". The particle と before it means "as".
For this も, please read this. Aととれない directly means "cannot interpret as A", but adding も turns it into a mild/euphemistic/reserved negation. That is, Aともとれない would mean something ambiguous like "not really interpretable as A".

So 頷くともとれないうつむき means "a bow not really interpretable as nodding" or "a bow that wasn't exactly like a nod". Basically, it's saying his gesture was ambiguous.

自分は頷くともとれないうつむきをして、これを受け取り、走り去った。
I gave an ambiguous bow that wasn't quite a nod, took it, and ran off.


Should the translation be more like this? "I kind of nodded, not to give an impression that I was bowing, grabbed the weapon and ran away". Doesn't the character wants to hide that he is grateful for receiving the weapon?
